# Mac (10.6.4) AFP Share (Network Applications) permissions issue

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, file-permissions, afp

I have a share point for the shared applications folder. This auto-mounts on clients correctly but when a file is created the permissions are such that the owner can't write to it (locally: root:wheel rw-r--r--  On the server: nobody:everyone rw-r--r-- group:group1 inherited allow read,write,execute,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown). The user is still able to delete the empty file.

I don't know what more info to provide, any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: A few questions to start off: What are the permissions on this directory on the server? Does the Share Point or the directory have ACLs in addition to the POSIX permissions? Is the user creating/saving the new file from within an application (if so, which one(s)) or dragging the file(s) to the directory using Finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `/Network/Applications` is mounted on the clients, it will be mounted before a user has logged in, so it will be mounted as a guest.  It will stay mounted as a guest even when a user logs in.  No matter what permissions you have on the client, the AFP server is mapping it to *nobody*.  Please have a look at my answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/144285):

> AFP uses a permission model that is quite different from NFS. Clients connect using their credentials, and then file access is controlled by the server. In some cases, [Privilege Mapping](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21221) occurs, which is the phenomenon you're describing.

In short, your clients will not reliably be able to create or modify anything in `/Network/Applications` because they will be doing so with no real credentials.  You could possibly use NFS instead of AFP, because NFS uses a (less secure) model of trusting the client computer to control file access.  However, you would be far better off using Mac OS X Server's concept of **Group Folders** to allow users to read and write using their own credentials.